# Fatal error: Call to a member function getChildHtml() on a non-object custom layouts

Tags: magento-1.9, page-layouts

I followed this tutorial on making custom page layouts: http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-cms-page-layout/
I then set my home page to that template but I now get an error of

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getChildHtml() on a non-object
```

but I'm not sure why though.. here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <custom>
                <class>Custom_CustomHomePage_Block</class>
            </custom>
        </blocks>
        <page>
            <layouts>
                <custom_home_page>
                    <label>Custom Home Page</label>
                    <template>page/customHomePage.phtml</template>
                </custom_home_page>
            </layouts>
        </page>
    </global>
</config>
```

this is the config.xml file found in /app/code/local/Custom/CustomHomePage/etc

and my Custom_CustomHomePage.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_CustomHomePage>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Custom_CustomHomePage>
    </modules>
</config>
```

this is found /app/etc/modules/

and my block class

```
<?php
    class Custom_CustomHomePage_Block extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
    }
?>
```

found /app/code/local/Custom/CustomHomePage/Block

I can't for the life of me see what's wrong :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Custom_CustomHomePage>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Custom_CustomHomePage>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
        <custom>
            <class>Custom_CustomHomePage_Block</class>
        </custom>
    </blocks>
    <page>
      <layouts>
        <custom_home_page translate="label">
          <label>Custom Home Page</label>
          <template>page/customHomePage.phtml</template>
        </custom_home_page>
      </layouts>
    </page>
  </global>
</config>
```

your Custom_CustomHomePage.xml file like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_CustomHomePage>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Page />
            </depends>
        </Custom_CustomHomePage>
    </modules>
</config>
```

add your page app/design/frontend/YOUR_INTERFACE/YOUR_THEME/template/page/customHomePage.phtml

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work :(

Comment: can you please post your template page code and error line no?

Comment: My bad need to update the question, no longer fatal error (I solved it by doing a tweak to my block code) - it now returns an empty string :( haha solve one problem and faced with another

Comment: Good you have mistake in  your class name in block file <?php
    class Custom_CustomHomePage_Block extends Mage_Core_Block_Template